# How do I handle clicks on the top app bar buttons to switch fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, button

I am working on an Android app using Android Studio's Basic Activity template. I have added a custom button to the top app bar named `action_book`

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.a2.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_book"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_book"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_book_24"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_settings_24"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

and I would like to implement a functionality where clicking this custom button switches to another fragment. I was thinking to modify the onOptionsItemSelected method to handle this button click.

Currently, my **`onOptionsItemSelected`** method looks like this:

```kotlin
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

However, if this is the right way to do it, I am unsure about how to handle the click events of my custom button inside this method .

If someone could please guide me on this I would be very grateful. Any code examples or step-by-step explanations would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's the right way, just add a function call to perform corresponding navigation to the required fragment.

I have shown basic navigation example, however I would highly suggest to use Navigation Components for navigation instead of this. You can learn more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started).

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> {
            settings()      // function call to navigate to required fragment
            true
        }
        R.id.action_book -> {
            book()          // function call to navigate to required fragment
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

fun book(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.home_fragment_host, new MyBookFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
}

fun settings(){
// write other navigation code here
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example of a function to navigate to the requested fragment?

Comment: I have added the basic navigation example, however I would highly suggest to use Navigation Components for navigation instead of this. You can learn more about it here https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started